# How to test a queued notification?

Tags: laravel

I have a `WelcomeNotification` which implements `ShouldQueue`

```php
class WelcomeNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        // send a welcome message to the user via mailtrap
    }

}
```

How can I test if this notification has been pushed to the queue?

I am trying to test it like this but I am getting 
`The expected [App\Notifications\WelcomeNotification] job was not pushed`

```php
    /** @test */
    public function welcome_notification_is_pushed_to_queue()
    {
        Queue::fake();

        $this->post(route('register'), [
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'email' => 'john@test.com',
            'password' => 'passwordtest',
        ]);

        Queue::assertPushed(WelcomeNotification::class);
    }
```

Inside my registered function in `RegisterController`:

```php
    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
          $user->notify(new WelcomeNotification());
          // other code
    }
```

I have successfully asserted that `WelcomeNotification` is correctly being sent to the user when registering using `Notification::assertSentTo`.

**My issue is how to test if `WelcomeNotification` was pushed to the queue or not?**

Comment: Same trouble. Both Queue::fake() + Queue::assertPushed and Notification::fake() + Notification::assertSentTo don't work... @rook99 have you resolved the test?

Answer (score 1):

If you dump `Queue::pushedJobs()` after faking the queue. You will find all queued jobs as an array where the array-key the job name. Actually, `Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications` is dispatched when your notification is queued.

```
/** @test */
public function welcome_notification_is_pushed_to_queue()
{
    Queue::fake();

    $this->post(route('register'), [
        'name' => 'John Doe',
        'email' => 'john@test.com',
        'password' => 'passwordtest',
    ]);
    
    // dd(Queue::pushedJobs());

    Queue::assertPushed(\Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications::class, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested on laravel 8.*
You need to check the `SendQueuedNotifications::class` for your queued notifications.
In closure while accessing the `$job`, you can also check the other goodies, like for how long it was delayed ( if your notification should be delayed `$job->delay` ) or if the notification should be sent like `method_exists($job->notification, 'shouldSend') && $job->motification->shouldSend()`.

```
public function testAttemptToQueueNotification()
{
    Queue::fake();

    $user = User::factory()->create();

    $user->notify(new SomeNotification);

    Queue::assertPushed(SendQueuedNotifications::class, function (SendQueuedNotifications $job) {
        return $job->notification::class === SomeNotification::class;
    });
}
```